# Есть ли оправдание всем (!) поставленным запятым? (→)

Tags: авторская-пунктуация

> Вдоль заброшенных, тоскливых домишек, обступивших заброшенную железную
>   дорогу, у заброшенного железнодорожного вокзала, на заброшенной,
>   поросшей травой дороге, в ожидании воды с далёких гор, лежали мешки с
>   песком, на высоту человеческого роста.

Ничего не тронуто. Понятно, что идёт нагнёт тоски.

Comment: Запятые расставлены в целом верно, однако есть некоторые спорные моменты обособления, однако они объясняются авторским желанием. Но пояснять каждую запятую я, конечно, не буду.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятые факультативны, Вы сами сказали, пояснением можно всё объяснить, но слишком много пояснений и уточнений для одного предложения. Конструкцию можно облегчить для понимания читателя, убрав одну из запятых и последнее пояснение отделив с помощью тире:

*Вдоль заброшенных, тоскливых домишек, обступивших заброшенную железную дорогу, у заброшенного железнодорожного вокзала, на заброшенной, поросшей травой дороге, в ожидании воды с далёких гор  лежали мешки с песком -  высотой в человеческий рост.*

Согласна с Александром: **"лежать на высоту"** никак не идёт. "Чешутся руки" усилить повторы указательными местоимениями:

*Вдоль заброшенных, тоскливых домишек, обступивших **такую же** заброшенную железную дорогу, у заброшенного **же**  вокзала, на заброшенной, поросшей травой дороге, в ожидании воды с далёких гор лежали мешки с песком - **стеной** в человеческий рост.* Но я знаю, что Вы не вмешиваетесь в авторскую лексику...

**Железнодорожного** просится удалиться, чтобы ещё одного повтора "дороги" избежать и сделать текст короче. И так понятно, что **железнодорожный** вокзал, ведь рядом - о **железной дороге**.

А вообще мне Ваш автор нравится, образ заброшенной местности понятен, мешки с песком в ожидании большой воды тоже, сразу рисуется, как дамба из этих мешков спасает жителей от затопления.

Answer (score 1):

Я читатель, я сейчас только читаю.

Ритмика мне нравится, всё соразмерно. Запятые тоже на месте: "в ожидании воды с далёких гор" можно считать уточнением.

Что хотелось бы поправить.

Слово "заброшенный" повторяется слишком часто.

Слово "дорога" повторяется.

Вдоль заброшенных, тоскливых домишек, обступивших заброшенную железную ДОРОГУ, у заброшенного железнодорожного вокзала, на ЗАТЕРЯННОЙ, поросшей травой ДОРОГЕ, в ожидании воды с далёких гор, лежали мешки с песком, на высоту человеческого роста.

ДОПОЛНЮ немного свой ответ после всех других ответов и комментариев.

Мне кажется, что не все чувствуют ритмику, музыкальность теста. Идет монотонный повтор отдельных фраз, примерно равных по объёму. Именно повтор и однообразие  создают, усиливают ощущение заброшенности места, это исправлять, дополнять, вмешиваться в авторское решение никак не желательно. Даже железная дорога и железнодорожный вокзал на месте — это тоже художественный прием (я пробовала их поправить, но получалось хуже). Вот только четырехкратное повторение слова "заброшенный" кажется мне лишним.

На высоту человеческого роста... Мне эта фраза при первом прочтении не показалась неправильной. Да, управление отсутствует, но так ли оно необходимо? Сочетание можно считать присоединительным, а там управление не требуется в обязательном порядке.

Это похоже на взгляд художника, когда он скользит по предмету, отмечает отдельые детали. Это — впечатление, которое записано словаи, что-то похожее на ипрессионизм в живописи. Будет жаль, если автор исправит текст.

Comment: Автор сейчас без Интернета! Но всё увидит, все замечания и рассуждения.

Comment: Хорошо, что еще  подумает. Я тоже сначала пыталась что-то поправить, потом сравнила полученные результаты с авторским вариантом и поняла, что он намного лучше всех правок.

Answer (score 1):

Мне мешают читать две запятые у "ожидания воды". Непонятно выражение "лежать на высоту" вместо обычного "быть высотой" (можно "высотой достигая").

Comment: Объяснить все запятые?

Comment: Саша, запятые тут - бог с ними, факультативны; а что там с высотой человеческого роста, есть же какое-то клише... с человеческий рост (без высоты или лёжки)? Напомни. А с водой - это буду мучить автора: я смысл не уловила - кто именно её ждет? мешки с песком? Ой.

Comment: Защищаю авторский текст. 1. В ожидании  могут находится любые предметы (обычное олицетворение), например: Меж креслами натекали лужицы: всплакнув, оттаивали валенки в ожидании тепла, света и музыки, чтоб опять уйти в ночь, в снег, в темень, потонуть в сугробах. [Андрей Соболь. Когда цветет вишня (1924)] 2. Лежали мешки с песком, (поднимаясь) на высоту человеческого роста.  Оборот обособленный, определяет высоту сооружения из мешков. Нельзя же в художественном тексте называть все  то, что и так ясно.  Изящная словесность не обязана быть строго реалистичной, автор прорисовывает  важные детали.

Comment: Упрощаю, поскольку в приведённых примерах не вижу аналогии с нашим текстом. _Вдоль домишек () в ожидании воды () лежали мешки._ Какое здесь основание для запятой мог бы привести автор? Вот если бы "ожидая воду"... На особенное по форме обстоятельство цели это "ожидание воды мешками" вряд ли тянет. :)

Comment: Галина, можно напр. "были выложены высотой в человеческий рост".

Comment: @БотБотович поясните, пожалуйста, что вы имели в виду?

Comment: Ответ на данную часть: *Мне мешают читать две запятые у "ожидания воды"*